# Check syntax of .conf file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

Tags: linux, x11

I have a new `.conf` file located in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` on my Manjaro Linux box which I would like to validate.

Is there a way of syntax checking it before `X` loads next time?

Comment: I do not understand why there is no solutions to this in the Linux community yet. X11 is notorious for preventing the system to boot into a graphical UI and often the reasons would be statically detectable. This would go a long way for Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `xntest` utility, which allows to launch a nested X server, but it seems to be dead. There is also `gdmflexiserver`, which is a mouthful, but has worked for me all right. It allows to create ondemand X servers, and with `--xnest` it would launch nested inside the running server.

Both solutions read your X config files, effectively validating them. Anything that would prevent a "real" X server from launching would probably crash a `gdmflexiserver` session.